# Hacer Consulta SQL

Tags: sql, table, as400

Hola a todos tengo una tabla de la siguiente manera, colocare unas cuantas filas para que entiendas la idea, esta es una tabla de articulos y algunos articulos van asociados a otros articulos, (veran que hay algunos con cantos y otros no), los articulos que tienen canto tienen el id de articulos de tipo canto (TABCAN = C)

| CODART | TABCAN | CODFAM | CODSUB | CODARN | MLARGOW | MANCHOW | MGRUES | CANTO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 168909 | C | CAN | PV82 | BLAN | 1000 | 23 | 1 |  |
| 190696 | C | CAN | PV82 | BLBR | 1000 | 23 | 1 |  |
| 319005 | T | MEF | LUXE | BL18 | 2750 | 1220 | 18 | 190696 |
| 324474 | T | MEF | LUXE | BL16 | 2750 | 1220 | 16 | 190696 |
| 324475 | T | MEF | LUXE | BL10 | 2750 | 1220 | 10 | 168909 |

necesito hacer un query sql para que me de como resultado la misma tabla (todos las filas) pero adicionando una nueva columna con la union de tres columnas de la misma tabla, EJEMPLO

| CODART | TABCAN | CODFAM | CODSUB | CODARN | MLARGOW | MANCHOW | MGRUES | CANTO | NUEVA_COLUMNA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 168909 | C | **CAN** | **PV82** | **BLAN** | 1000 | 23 | 1 |  |  |
| 190696 | C | **CAN** | **PV82** | **BLBR** | 1000 | 23 | 1 |  |  |
| 319005 | T | MEF | LUXE | BL18 | 2750 | 1220 | 18 | 190696 | **CANPV82BLBR** |
| 324474 | T | MEF | LUXE | BL16 | 2750 | 1220 | 16 | 190696 | **CANPV82BLBR** |
| 324475 | T | MEF | LUXE | BL10 | 2750 | 1220 | 10 | 168909 | **CANPV82BLAN** |

Espero se haya entendido mi duda y puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx. Te faltó decirnos cuál es el código que estar usando y qué error ves

Comment: hola, el problema es que soy algo nuevo en SQL y no se como hacer la consulta SQL, jejeje

Comment: Pues te toca intentarlo y fallar ;)

Comment: he intentado cosas como esta SELECT ARTICULOS.*, ARTICULOS.CODFAM||ARTICULOS.CODSUB||ARTICULOS.CODARN AS NUEVA_COLUMNA FROM LAM2000F.ARDARTL1 ARTICULOS ORDER BY TABCAN , pero no hacen lo que necesito, me imagino que necesito hacer un join pero no se

Comment: Pareciera que `CANTO`  esta determinando la relación con las dos filas superiores ¿has probado hacer un `left join` a la misma tabla por esta columna y luego concatenar los datos?